# Regular expression for matching two digits following anything not 'k' or ' k'

Tags: regex, regex-negation

How do I create a regex where I need to match with two digits followed by any thing but 'k' or ' k'?
For example:

```
['10', '10 a', '10 k', '10k']
```

In the given array only the elements '10' and '10 a' should be matched.

I tried `[0-9]{2}(^k| k)` but it didn't give me the expected result.

Comment: Is it JS/JSON ?

Comment: `\b\d{2}\b(?!\s*k\b)` if that is a string.

Comment: it is a node JS

Answer (score 2):

To match a number containing only two digits that is not followed with a single word `k` with a space or no space before it, you can use

```
\b\d{2}\b(?!\s*k\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pb4XcA/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!\s*k\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are zero or more whitespaces followed with `k` and a word boundary immediately to the right of the current location.

Note that your array items start with numbers, so it makes sense to replace the first word boundary with a `^` start of string anchor.

In JS, you can use

```js
const arr = ['10', '10 a', '10 k', '10k'];
console.log(arr.filter(x => /^\d{2}\b(?!\s*k\b)/.test(x)));
```

Output:

```
[
  "10",
  "10 a"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

### With `js`:

```js
['10', '10 a', '10 k', '10k']
.filter(x => /\b\d{2}(?!\s*k)/
.test(x))
.forEach(x => console.log(x))
```

### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `\b` | the boundary between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char |
| `\d{2}` | digits (0-9) (2 times) |
| `(?!` | [negative look ahead](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) to see if there is not: |
| `\s*` | whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `k` | k |
| `)` | end of look-ahead |

### Output

```
10
10 a
```